# Difference in HTTP request from browser and curl

Tags: api, rest, captcha

So I was interesting in using Norwegians API and in my browser I can perfectly use.
E.g.

https://www.norwegian.com/api/fare-calendar/calendar?adultCount=2&destinationAirportCode=PARALL&originAirportCode=CPH&outboundDate=2022-02-01&inboundDate=2022-05-01&tripType=2&currencyCode=DKK&languageCode=da-DK&pageId=258774&eventType=user

It works in incognito so it doesn't seem to be dependent on a cookie.

So I tried using the Dev Tools to copy a curl equivalent command:

```
curl 'https://www.norwegian.com/api/fare-calendar/calendar?adultCount=2&destinationAirportCode=PARALL&originAirportCode=CPH&outboundDate=2022-02-01&inboundDate=2022-05-01&tripType=2&currencyCode=DKK&languageCode=da-DK&pageId=258774&eventType=user' \
  -H 'authority: www.norwegian.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 Edg/93.0.961.52' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: da' \
  --compressed
```

However using this I'm getting hit by a "Are you human?"-check which is perfectly fair but it got me wonder how their service can differentiate between the two HTTP request. Is the browser sending some additional information which is not disclosed?

Answer (score 0):

Some sites can actually check the width of your screen. i.e something like this website bestfirms.com/what-is-my-screen-resolution. You can not get past this because curl cant run javascript.

Comment: Good suggestion but that means some javascript has to be served but when I examine the two requests there are no javascript at all.